# frontend submit post jQuery clone row won't save

Tags: custom-field, front-end, save-post, customization

Why the cloned value won't save in DB ?
It's working fine for the first row (not the cloned one) but when I add new value with jQuery(.clone), new added value won't save...

jQuery

```
$('#add-embed').on('click', function() {
    var row = $('.empty-row').clone(true);
        row.removeClass('empty-row').addClass('entries');
        row.insertBefore('#repeater > div:last');
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="repeater">
    <div class="entries">
        <input type="text" name="al_ttl[]">
        <input type="text" name="al_tmp[]">
    </div>
    <div class="empty-row">
        <input type="text" name="al_ttl[]">
        <input type="text" name="al_tmp[]">
    </div>
</div>
```

Save

```
function frontend_submit() {
    global $current_user, $post;

    if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
        && !empty( $_POST['action'] )
        && $_POST['action'] == 'post' ) {

        //Global Post
        $post_id        = $post->ID;
        $user_id        = $current_user->ID;
        $post_title     = $_POST['post_title'];


        $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
            'post_author'   => $user_id,
            'post_title'    => $post_title,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'test'
        ));


        //Data Rows Save
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, 'data_rows', true);
        $new = array();
        $ah_ttl = $_POST['al_ttl'];
        $ah_tmp = $_POST['al_tmp'];
        $count = count( $ah_ttl );
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
            if ( $ah_ttl[$i] != '' ) :
                $new[$i]['al_ttl'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $ah_ttl[$i] ) );
                $new[$i]['al_tmp'] = stripslashes( $ah_tmp[$i] );

            endif;
        }

        if ( !empty( $new ) && $new != $old )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'data_rows', $new );
        elseif ( empty($new) && $old )
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'data_rows', $old );

        }

}
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'frontend_submit');
```

Comment: I didn't read every line of code, but I'm pretty confused as to what is going on here. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Cloned field value won't save when I submit my post from frontend. Im using jQuery to clone input.

Comment: What code you are using to fetch the records? Have seen the data in database, how is it look in there?

Comment: My data is serialized. I use foreach to fetch...

Comment: have you tried to call `var_dump($_POST['al_ttl']); die();` in your `frontend_submit` function to see if your cloned row values are actually there. You can also use your browser's network inspector to see if your cloned row has the fields values passed. Please check this and report back.

Comment: It's a jQuery problem and I don't know how to solve it... I added the title value of the post inside the jquery clone and when I add new row with the title value it didn't save.

Comment: How do you know it is a jQuery problem? That seems very unlikely given the simplicity of the jQuery code you have shared. Have you tried @AlexanderHolsgrove's suggestion? What was the result?

Comment: I have this result `Notice: Undefined index: al_ttl in /var/www/... NULL`

Comment: Ah! `$new[$i]` is never initialized - try throwing a `$new[$i] = array()` right before `$new[$i]['al_ttl'] = stripslashes(//...`

Comment: I got same result :/

Comment: is your  `<div id='repeater'>` properly inside `<form>` tag of your page ( I assume you're in a form  since your code does not provide  an ajax function)

Comment: Also note that you're overwriting the first initialization of `$post_id` with `wp_insert_post` and after that you're looking for a post_meta `$old = get_post_meta($post_id, 'data_rows', true);` which will always be empty being on the new post

Comment: ... I took care of my function rather than taking care of my form ... Everything working fine with my function except my form(html)... wrong closing form... 1 week for this lol I'm going to take a little vacation x) THANK YOU Andrea Somovigo you make my day and all other ppl tried to help me!

Comment: It would be nice to get the bounty .. I'm writing an answer instead of a comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check if your `<div id='repeater'>` is properly inside `<form>` tag of your page ( I assume you're in a form since your code does not provide an ajax function) and from what you outpup with `var_dump($_POST['al_ttl'])` it may be the reason of `Undefined index: al_ttl`.

Also note that you're overwriting the first initialization of `$post_id` with `wp_insert_post` and after that you're looking for a post_meta `$old = get_post_meta($post_id, 'data_rows', true);` which will always be empty being on the new post

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Everything working fine with my function except my form(html)... wrong closing form. That's why the cloned field won't save.